# Seeking national MLS boundary dataset for US

Tags: data, united-states, administrative-boundaries, business

What I am looking for is some type (any type) of national map which outlines the boundaries of each of the 1000+ MLS (Multiple Listing Services).

For some reason the National Association of Realtors will not release this data.

Do you have any type of source for this info, even if it's just the exact zip codes covered by each MLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not directly answer your question in terms of how and/or where to obtain the data, but may serve as some guidance as to why you cannot find it readily available and why the National Association of Realtors does not release the data: [MLS Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_listing_service)

Read the sections entitled Limitations of access and Criticisms of MLS and [Policies on sharing MLS data in the USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_listing_service#Policies_on_sharing_MLS_data_in_the_USA).